# How to write string literals in sql query in springboot application.yaml file?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, apache-kudu

I am trying to place sql query to read data from kudud table in applciation.yaml file where string literal is used.
But while running the program it is giving the parsing error as below -
EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rcurly(})' but was 'identifier'

Below is the query used where "FINNACE" is a literal-

application.yaml -
filequery.map : '{

"filequery"                                    : "SELECT FILE,
project
FROM
( SELECT FILE AS file_or_table_group,
**"FINNACE" AS project**
FROM finnance_data ) AS finnancedata"

}'

Comment: Did you try :`\"FINNACE\"` ?

Comment: Yes @SeanH, I tried this also.

Comment: Not sure why,  but I think you can save this json content into a separate json file and let your code to load it separately. That's possibly can separate the issues.

Comment: @SeanH, It got resolved, we need to provide " to escape " means it should be like - ""FINNANCE"". Thanks

Comment: Good news.  Thanks.